# SUMMA matrix multiplication with transposed matrices

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to implement the SUMMA distributed matrix multiplication algorithm specified here: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn96.pdf. I have successfully implemented the algorithm for the cases $ C = A B$ and $C = A B^T$ (I don't care about the $ + \beta C $).

For the cases $C = A^T B^T$ and $C = A^T B$, however, the paper gives only the very brief descriptions in sections 6 and 8 respectively; for example:

> Forming $C = A^T B^T$ can easily be derived by noting that $C^T = BA$ and reversing the roles of rows and columns in the algorithm given in Section 5.

It's not clear to me what it means to "reverse the roles of rows and columns". If one uses the unblocked, serial algorithm, in which $C = AB$ is formulated as the sum of outer products between the columns of A and the rows of B, one can indeed form $\tilde{C} = A^T B^T$ as the sum of outer products between the rows of A and the columns of B.

However, it seems that once these outer products are blocked together, the respective blocks must themselves be transposed explicitly. In the distributed case it becomes unclear how to achieve this: individually transposing only the local blocks available to each processor, for example, returns $\tilde{C}^T$ rather than $\tilde{C}$.

Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Why do the blocks need to be transposed separately? Can't you just calculate $C = BA$, and then transpose the resulting matrix to get $C^T = A^TB^T$?

Comment: You certainly could, but then you'd have to do the explicit transpose, and the goal is to avoid doing that since the matrix is highly distributed

Comment: (suppose the processor network is highly rectangular, for example, so that $C$ but not $C^T$ fits in memory)

Comment: When the SUMMA paper was written, it was indeed not obvious how to do the $ C = A^T B^T $ case without explicit transposition (and hence temporary space.  The answer can now be found in https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140993478, which is probably the definitive resource for practical distributed memory parallel matrix-matrix multiplicatio.